# Disappearing printf befor while(true)

Tags: c, string, while-loop, printf

I had to do a little test in my code so I wrote something like this :

```
printf("Some stuff");
while(true){
    //Some other stuff
}
```

But my printf was absent in my terminal.

Adding **\n** at the end of my string solved the problem.

Why did my printf disappeared ?

Comment: This is called _line buffering_. Try `printf("Some stuff\n");`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called buffering - you need to flush the buffer

Use

```
fflush(stdout);
```

after the `printf` to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification